# cinelerra: error while loading shared libraries: libavcodec.so.52 slackware

Tags: installation, shared-libraries, libavcodec, libav, slackware

indeed it takes days trying to install cinelerra and no longer know what else to do eh searched forums and I have sent emails to the list of cinelerra still can not solve anything thanks in advance

just interested in using cinelerra I have slackware 13.37 Download the TXZ of

```
http://repository.slacky.eu/slackware-13.37/multimedia/cinelerra/20110512/cinelerra-20110512-i486-1sl.txz
```

says that it installs correctly put:

```
# cinelerra
```

and I get the following error:

```
cinelerra: error while loading shared libraries: libavcodec.so.52: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Download ffmpeg-0.7 from slacky.eu and install it. This will solve problem with missing libavcodec.so.52